# psycopg2 AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'mogrify'

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, psycopg2, database-cursor

I have a class that helps me with SQL queries and inserts in Postgres.  I'm using `psycopg2==2.7.5` right now.  One of the methods I'm using looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd    
import psycopg2.extensions as ps_ext
from typing import List

def insert_with_open_connection(self, df: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str, cursor: ps_ext.cursor,
                                conn: ps_ext.connection,
                                success_msg: str = 'Success',
                                conflict_cols: List[str] = None):
    try:
        # Format the INSERT SQL query
        cols = str(tuple(df.columns)).replace("'", '')
        nc = df.shape[1]
        ss = "(" + ''.join('%s,' for _ in range(nc))[:-1] + ")"
        try:
            args_str = str(b','.join(cursor.mogrify(ss, x) for x in df.values), 'utf-8')
        except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
            args_str = str(b','.join(cursor.mogrify(ss, x) for x in self.clean_numpy_int_for_mogrify(df.values)),
                           'utf-8')
        args_str = args_str.replace("\'NaN\'::float", 'NULL')
        insert_sql = f'INSERT INTO {table_name} {cols} VALUES {args_str}'
        if conflict_cols is not None:
            conf_cols = str(tuple(conflict_cols)).replace("'", '').replace(',)', ')')
            insert_sql += f"\nON CONFLICT {conf_cols} DO NOTHING"
        insert_sql += ';'
        cursor.execute(insert_sql)
        conn.commit()
        return success_msg, 200
    except Exception:
        return traceback.format_exc(), 400
```

The `conn` and `cursor` parameters are generated from a SqlAlchemy `Engine` with code like this:

```
def create_pool(self, **db_config):
    db_user = self.user
    db_pass = self.password
    db_name = self.database

    # e.g. "/cloudsql"
    db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")

    # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
    cloud_sql_connection_name = os.environ.get("CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME",
                                               '<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>')

    self.pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

        # Equivalent URL:
        # postgresql+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
        #                     ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
                                         username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
                                         password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
                                         database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
                                         query={"unix_sock":
                                                    f"{db_socket_dir}/{cloud_sql_connection_name}/.s.PGSQL.5432"}),
        **db_config
    )

def get_db_connection(self) -> Connection:
    if self.pool is None:
        self.create_pool()

    assert isinstance(self.pool, Engine)
    try:
        return self.pool.raw_connection()
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        self.create_pool()
        return self.pool.raw_connection()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def db_connect(self):
    db = self.get_db_connection()
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        yield db, cur
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I'm trying to use this code inside a Google Cloud Function (Linux) and I get the following error/traceback when I run the `insert_with_open_connection` method there:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/db/sql_helper.py", line 221, in insert_with_open_connection
    args_str = str(b','.join(cursor.mogrify(ss, x) for x in df.values), 'utf-8')
  File "/workspace/db/sql_helper.py", line 221, in <genexpr>
    args_str = str(b','.join(cursor.mogrify(ss, x) for x in df.values), 'utf-8')
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'mogrify'
```

It's obvious that the `cursor` in the code doesn't seem to have the attribute `mogrify`, but based on the docs [here](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/psycopg2/2.7.5/cursor.html), the `mogrify` method should exist.

Comment: Not sure but it possible that `Cursor` is a SqlAlchemy class. Cursor wrapper for all supported databases but not instance of `ps_ext.cursor` class. Try to `print(type(cursor))` and `print(dir(cursor))`  to understand exact class of object and supported methods

Comment: Ahh!  it's a `pg8000.legacy.Cursor` not a `ps_ext.cursor`.  That would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the code and noticed that you were using `import psycopg2.extensions as ps_ext`; and clearly that had `mogrify` in
the docs.

Then I came across this line:

```
self.pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

        # Equivalent URL:
        # postgresql+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
        #                     ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
                                         username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
                                         password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
                                         database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
                                         query={"unix_sock":
                                                    f"{db_socket_dir}/{cloud_sql_connection_name}/.s.PGSQL.5432"}),
        **db_config
    )
```

You aren't using the psycopg2 driver; but the pg8000 one and tracing
the way things are generated, the cursor as returned by the `db.cursor()` which in turn was created by the self.pool.raw_connection(),
I came to the conclusion that the cursor wasn't a ps_ext cursor but
a pg8000 cursor, which doesn't have the `mogrify` method as
shown in: https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/blob/main/pg8000/dbapi.py

This is the likelihood of why you're having this error.  I think
the solution is to change to using psycopg2 driver instead.

That said,  this answer could be wrong and I'm barking up the wrong tree.